# Mongoose - Can't explain population

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, mongoose

I'm doing a certain query, and I want to get the executionTime of it (including the popualtion):

```
  const managerId = "023492745"

  const company = await Companies.find({
    _id: "1234"
  })
    .populate(
      {
        path: "employees",
        match: {
          _id: { $ne: managerId },
        },
      })
    .explain()
```

I try to use `explain()` on the query, but all It only retrieves information about the `find()` part and not about the `populate()` part. How can I get the executionTime of the whole query?

Answer (score 0):

`explain` is a command executed by the mongodb server, while `populate` is a function executed on the client side by mongoose.

The `populate` function works by receiving the results of the `find` from the server, then submitting additional queries to retrieve the corresponding data to place in each document.

The response to the `explain` command does not contain the found documents, only the statistics and metadata about the query, so there is nothing for `populate` to operate on.

Instead of explain, you might try increasing the log verbosity or enabling profiling on the mongod server to capture the subsequent queries.

Comment: I tried enabling profiling but got an error: "profile currently not supported via mongos". Have any idea what to do?

Comment: in a sharded cluster, enable profiling on the shard mongod nodes, not the mongos